# How can I determine what is the basis of a code?

Tags: coding-theory

I need to determine what is the basis of a set of vectors that are in GF(2).
The code is :
C={00000000,11100010,10100101,01000111,01101001,10001011,11001100,00101000,11010001,00110011,01110100,10010110,10111000,01011010,00011101,11111111}

This vectors should be linearly independent. Any help? !
[Here's the original basis's code] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UBER.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what a basis is? Do you know that this code $C$ is a subspace? Do you know its dimension? Can you find a linearly independent subset of $C$?

Comment: I know that is a set of vectors that generate the whole code with linear combinations. This code is a parity check code that I created from a system of equations. I think that his dimension should be the same as the original code that is 4.

Comment: Great so far! What happens if you pick four elements of the code however you want; do you know how to check whether they are linearly independent?

Comment: I know that I should put them in row echelon form and take a look. But isn't there a shortcut to not prove all possible combinations? Thanks in advance. Mm by the way I was thinking in convert the basis of the original code into a parity check basis but this not seems to work.

Comment: A thing to keep in mind is that there is no such thing as *the* basis. There are several. In fact, a 4-dimensional vector space over $GF(2)$ has $840$ different bases (assuming you consider two permutations of the same basis as equal). If you pick a random collection of four non-zero vectors there is a roughly 60 per cent chance that they form a basis.